# Why it is showing different size?

Tags: c, charts, types, integer, sizeof

Why this statement show 2 bytes whereas there is only a single character in string

```
printf("%d = Bytes", sizeof("a"));
```

Why this statement show 4 bytes whereas there is only a single character in a character.

```
printf("%d = Bytes", sizeof('a'));
```

Comment: In C all literal strings (the ones with double quotes `"`) are really non-modifiable *arrays* of the characters in them ***plus the string null terminator***.

Comment: By the way, the `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`, which you really need to use the format `%zu` to print. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Complementary to @Someprogrammerdude type mismatch - compiler warnings have a reason...

Comment: The type of `'a'` is `int` which appears to have a size of 4 bytes.

Comment: BTW, Rarely used wide character constants like  `sizeof('abcde')` is also 4.

Answer (score 2):

String literals, this: `"a"` are equivalent of character arrays in C. If you use `sizeof` on them you get the size of the array. `a` and the null terminator `\0` are 2 bytes so you get 2. Not to be confused with `strlen("a")` which would give 1.

`'a'` is a character constant. Oddly enough, these are of type `int` in C, for historical reasons. And *not* `char` which would make sense. This is kind of a C language defect. In C++ they fixed this problem and there character literals have size 1. But in C, `sizeof('a')` will always equal `sizeof(int)`. On your system this is apparently 4 bytes.